# What is this code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

```
gnSaveOnExit = If(gnSaveOnExit = 0, 1, 0)
```

What is it saying? That if gnSaveOnexit is 0, the statement is true or else this is false?
or gnSaveOnExit will change from 0 to 1 and from other values to 0?

Comment: Have you copied this verbatim? Isn't it actually using `IIf`?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, `If(x, y, z)` and `IIf(x, y, z)` are distinct expressions.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Oh. With distinct behaviours, too?

Comment: Yes. `IIf` does not short circuit, `If` does. So in `IIf(x(), y(), z())`, all three methods will run. In `If(x(), y(), z())`, `y()` or `z()` will only be run based on the true/false result of `x()`

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like an inline if statement that will flip the value of `gnSaveOnExit` between 0 and 1.

If the only valid values are 0 and 1, this could be converted to a Boolean value. The statement would then simply be:

```
bnSaveOnExit = Not bnSaveOnExit
```

...even though that really doesn't make any sense without some kind of context.

Answer (score 2):

This is short hand for:

```
If gnSaveOnExit = 0 Then
    gnSaveOnExit = 1
else
    gnSaveOnExit = 0
end If
```

In other words: If `gnSaveOnExit = 0`, set it to `1`. If its anything else, set it to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Its switching non-zero values to zero, and zero values to 1. Presumably gnSaveOnExit would only be 1 or 0 anyway. I'm not sure why a boolean hasn't been used.

An equivalent (just for fun!) would be

```
   gnSaveOnExit = -1 * (gnSaveOnExit - 1)
```

Comment: Seems an odd choice. Would gnSaveOnExit not in (0,1) be a logical thing for the code to support?

Comment: `-1 * (gnSaveOnExit - 1)` is equivalent to `1 - gnSaveOnExit`, but it breaks when the initial value of `gnSaveOnExit` is something other than 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

First" Should be IIF no If

Should read IIF(gnSaveOnExit = 0, 1, 0)

If gnsaveonexit = 0 then 1 else 0

When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes False and all other values become True. When Visual Basic converts Boolean values to numeric types, False becomes 0 and True becomes -1.

Comment: Am pretty sure that If(,,) is valid in recent versions of VB.Net. As Anthony Pegram says above. They have different behaviours. Not sure if there is an equivalent in c#. However there was no If(,,) statement in VB6

Comment: See comments to the question, you may be enlightened. :)

Comment: @Jon - Yes, you can use `If` now. I think it was only added in the most recent version

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Equivalent to the `If` shorthand in C#, would be `a = a == 0 ? 1 : 0;` - not certain about evaluation of both outcomes in C#, though.

Comment: `x() ? y() : z()` in C# short circuits as well.